# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension' not found

Tags: php, symfony, twig-extension

I've tried updating Symfony to v2.7.40 today. At the end of the update process while clearing the cache I encounter

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension' not found

In my composer.json I already have required and installed "twig/extensions": "~1.5"
Do I need to update any other bundle/library?
Thank you

Comment: I fixed it by also updating twig/twig. I guess it's a problem with the composer.json files of each project as they are not compatible in any combination.